# Embedding UML diagrams in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml

I have only seen gems that can generate UML diagrams for rails classes themselves. 
 I want a gem/tool that can allow for *creating and embedding UML diagrams(sequence diagrams in particular) in rails*. Does anyone have suggestions for open-source UML visualization tools that can be integrated into a rails app? Perhaps one that has XML input and output capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a gem for a UML renderer in rails apps, but you could create your own. If you're looking for guidance on how to do it, the first chapter of the book "Crafting Rails Applications" is about creating your own custom renderer for use in rails. If there's already a ruby gem that can generate UML ([this looks like a pretty good option](http://rubygems.org/gems/yumlcmd)), it wouldn't be too hard. If not, if you can find a command line app that can create UML diagrams, that wouldn't be terribly difficult to integrate either.